# Range em Python - Números em ordem decrescente

Tags: python

Preciso gerar uma lista com números pares de `N` até `0`.

Por exemplo, se eu informar `8`, tenho que imprimir `14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0`. O meu programa, abaixo, está retornando 9 números, indo até o `16`. Onde errei, por gentileza? :)

```
numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro positivo e par: '))
while numero <= 0 or numero % 2 != 0:
    print('O número não pode ser zero, ímpar ou negativo!')
    numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro positivo e par: '))
while numero > 0 or numero % 2 == 0:
    for n in range(numero + numero, - 1, - 2):
        print(n)
    break
```

Comment: Arruma a formatação e identação do código, por favor :)

Comment: "*se eu informar 8, tenho que imprimir 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14*", não deveria ser em ordem **decrescente**?

Comment: Isso, errei ao descrever...rsrsrs

Comment: `0, 2, 4, 6, 8..` está em ordem crescente. Vc quer ordem crescente ou decrescente?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479716/137387

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma muito fácil é utilizar a função range do Python
Tente esta função:

```
def f(n):
for i in range((n-1)*2, -1, -2):
    print(i)
```

Ao utilizar a função `range(start, end, step)`, se utilizar um step negativo, terá os números por ordem decrescente
Aqui pode encontrar mais detalhes e alguns exemplos do uso da função range:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Comment: Olá Rafael! Muitíssimo obrigado! :)

Comment: Agora, por exemplo, no algoritmo abaixo, para números ĩmpares, não estou conseguindo, também.

Comment: `numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro positivo e ímpar: '))
while numero <= 0 or numero % 2 == 0:
    print('O número não pode ser zero, par ou negativo!')
    numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro positivo e ímpar: '))
while numero > 0 or numero % 2 != 0:
    for n in range(numero, 0, - 2):
        print(n)
    break`

Comment: Eu queria informar, aĩ em cima, 5, e o programa retornar 5 números em ordem decrescente, todos ímpares. Desculpem pelos problemas na formatação, pessoal. :( Não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 0):

A forma como você construiu o algoritmo você precisa tirar 2 do start do `range(start, stop, step)`:

```
numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro positivo e par: '))
while numero <= 0 or numero % 2 != 0:
    print('O número não pode ser zero, ímpar ou negativo!')
    numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro positivo e par: '))
else:
    for n in range((numero + numero) - 2, - 1, - 2):
        print(n)
```

Entrada:

```
Informe um número inteiro positivo e par: 8
```

Saída:

```
14
12
10
8
6
4
2
0
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi, você deseja implementar um código que seja capaz de exibir os **N** primeiros números **pares** em ordem invertida.

Uma outra forma de se resolver esta questão é:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
i = 0
pares = list()
while len(pares) <= n - 1:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(i)
    i += 1

print(sorted(pares, reverse=True))
```

Observe que este código é capaz de exibir todos os números **pares** entre **0 e N** - Independentemente de quem seja este N.

**Testando o código:**

Ao executar o código, digitar o valor **8** e pressionar `enter`, recebermos como resultado:

```
[14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é utilizando o laço `for`. O código ficaria:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
pares = list()
for i in range(0, (2 * n)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(i)
print(sorted(pares, reverse=True))
```

Outra forma de resolver é utilizando **List Comprehension**. Neste caso o código seria:

```
pares = [i for i in range(0, (2 * int(input('Digite um número: ')))) if i % 2 == 0]
print(sorted(pares, reverse=True))
```

Se não quiser montar uma lista, para depois exibi-la, podes utilizar o código:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
m = (2 * (n - 1))
while m >= 0:
    if m % 2 == 0:
        print(m)
    m -= 1
```

ou

```
n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
for i in range((2 * (n - 1)), -1, -2):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i, end=' ')
print()
```

Comment: É que não cheguei nessa parte ainda no curso.

Comment: @EWSG, citei três formas de resolver. A primeiro com laço `while`, a segunda com laço `for` e a terceira com `List Comprehension`. Você pode utilizar uma das três. Todas elas lhe dará o resultado desejado.

Comment: @EWSG, Se você digitar `8`, receberás como resultado uma lista com `8 números pares incluindo 0`. Se você digitar `5`, receberás como resultado uma lista com `5 números pares` e assim por diante.

Comment: Deu certinho. Obrigado, amigo. :)