# Como reduzir código Python 3?

Tags: python, algoritmo

um simples algoritmo para ler um inteiro X e imprimir os próximos 6 ímpares (inclusive o  X se ímpar)

```
X = int(input())
if X % 2 == 1:
    print(X)
    X+=2
    for i in range(5):
        if X % 2 == 1:
            print(X)
            X+=2
else: 
    X+=1
    for i in range(6):
        if X % 2 == 1:
            print(X)
            X+=2
```

De que forma posso reduzir o código (Python 3)?

Comment: Esse problema está definido certo? Porque eu não consigo imaginar porque ele deveria ser tão complicado.

Comment: Se você já garantiu que x é ímpar (somando 1 quando é par, por exemplo), e está incrementando de 2 em 2, não tem porque testar de novo dentro do `for`

Comment: Não questionando o conteúdo da resposta aceita(eu mesmo dei um upvote na resposta) e nem questionando escolha, mas eu vi que você marcou como aceitas todas as respostas ao clicar no "✅" de todas elas. Veja em [como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/137387), o funcionamento da ferramenta de aceitação de respostas. Em resumo você pode votar em todas as resposta mas deve aceitar apenas uma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se `ficar pequeno` é premissa

```
X = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
print([o+X for o in list(range(12)) if ((o+X) % 2) == 1])
```

**Update**: Utilizei `list comprehension`. Se quiser saber mais sobre `list comprehension` veja [aqui na documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) - item 5.1.3

**Porém** na resposta do @Maniero o loop é menor, consumindo menos tempo para processamento...

**Update 2**

Pequeno e eficiente:

```
X = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
print([2 * o + 1 for o in range((X - X % 2) // 2, ((X - X % 2) // 2) + 6)])
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 6):

Não vou me preocupar com falha se a pessoa não digitar um número válido.

Tem que mudar o valor de `x` para a próxima unidade se ela não for ímpar, caso contrário não deve mudar, então o incremento deve ser condicional.

O [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) é bem poderoso e você pode estabelecer a sequência ali mesmo. Você pode colocar qual deve ser o número de início da sequência, já devidamente garantido que é um ímpar, depois qual é o número que deve para, portanto como quer 6 e só deve pegar os ímpares é esse mesmo número que já tem mais 12, e deve indicar que deve pular de 2 em 2, conforme pode ser visto na documentação da função *linkada*.

Também não pode esquecer que se quer imprimir os valores da sequência tem que pegar a variável do laço e não mais o `x` que foi usado para dar parâmetros para a sequência ser gerada, não é o item individual de cada passo que irá variar, então pegamos o `i`.

Dá para simplificar mais, mas acho que não é hora para aprender essas coisas.

```
x = int(input())
if x % 2 == 0:
    x += 1
for i in range(x, x + 12, 2):
    print(i)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SYhJrn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bgjmkjzs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Range.py).

Answer (score 3):

Como já citado em outras respostas esse código não se preocupa em afirmar a validade ou não da entrada do usuário.

```
n = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))    
g = (n - n % 2 ) // 2                         #Calcula a geratriz de n usando sua paridade.
print([2 * i + 1 for i in range(g, g + 6)])   #Computa os seis próximos ímpares usando a geratriz.
```

<sup>Teste esse exemplo no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GruesomeFrightenedApplicationprogrammer)</sup>

Alguns conceitos para ajudar a entender o algoritmo:

## Paridade

Paridade é uma noção aplicada ao conjunto dos números inteiros onde um número inteiro qualquer é dito par se  ao ser dividido pelo número dois resulta em um número inteiro, caso contrário esse número é dito ímpar. Podendo afirmar:

- para um par o resto de sua divisão inteira por 2 será sempre 0.
- para um ímpar o resto de sua divisão inteira por 2 será sempre 1.

## Conjuntos dos pares e conjuntos do impares

O conjunto dos números pares é o conjunto dos números inteiros divisíveis por dois, ou seja a divisão por dois é fechada no conjunto dos inteiros. Esse conjunto é descrito pela função:

> *nₚ* = 2 * *n* | *n* ∈ **Z**
> <sub>o número par é igual duas vezes o número n tal que n pertença aos inteiros</sub>

Por sua vez o conjunto dos números impares é o conjunto dos números inteiros não divisíveis por dois, ou seja a divisão por dois é aberta no conjunto dos inteiros. Esse conjunto é descrito pela função:

> *nₗ* = 2 * *n* + 1 | *n* ∈ **Z**
> <sub>o número impar é igual a duas vezes n mais 1 tal que n pertença aos inteiros</sub>

## Geratrizes

Geratriz é o que gera ou que dá origem quanto a paridade podemos dizer que:

- A geratriz do numero par, o número *n* que gerou *nₚ*

> *gₚ* = *nₚ* / 2
> <sub>a geratriz par é igual ao número par dividido por 2</sub>

- A geratriz do número impar, o número *n* que gerou *nₗ*:

> *gₗ* = ( *nₗ* - 1 ) / 2
> <sub>a geratriz impar é igual ao número impar menos um dividido por 2</sub>

Se aplicarmos a noção paridade e termos `%` como o operador resto da divisão inteira, podemos generalizar o cálculo da geratriz da seguinte forma:

> *g* = ( *n* - *n* % 2 ) / 2 | *n* ∈ **Z**
> <sub>a geratriz paritária dum numero inteiro é igual a divisão por dois de n menos o resto de sua divisão por 2, tal que n pertença aos inteiros</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa com o join:

```
n = int(input())
if n % 2 == 0:
    n +=1
    
' '.join(str(v) for v in range(n, n + 12, 2))
```

ou

```
n = int(input())
' '.join(str(v) for v in range(n, n + 12) if v % 2 == 1)
```